# How to align the text to the top in a nav tab bootstrap UI(angularjs)?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

How to align the content inside a uib-tab to the top. I used margin bottom and tried other css properties, but its not working?
https://next.plnkr.co/plunk/kQkxl7r4phRSk9GO

Comment: Can't understand what your issue is

Comment: why do you want it "aligned" to the top, what have you actually tried ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didnt properly understand the question but if u want to align the text to top for nav-tab-links then use this css

`.nav>li>a {
padding-top: 0 !important;
}`